# input button not working when form is used

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code :

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <br/>
    <div id="buttons">
        <input id="search" onclick="search()" type="button" value="Search"/>
        <input type="button" value="Random"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function search() {
            var search = document.getElementById('search');
            var int = setInterval(function() {
                if (search.value.length == 6) search.value = 'Searchi';
                else if (search.value.length == 7) 
                    search.value = 'Searchin';
                else if (search.value.length == 8) 
                    search.value = 'Searching';
                else {
                    search.value = 'Search';
                }
                //clearInterval( int ); // at some point, clear the setInterval
            }, 500);
        }​
        </script>
    </div>
    </form>
```

the button function is not working when `<form>` element is in the code. by removing the form element you will see that the JavaScript works! I want to know what is the problem? and how can I fix it?

Also, is there a better code for the result that I want? Somebody told me that I am using an old method of JavaScript!

Comment: `int` is a reserved word in javascript.

Comment: that won't fix the problem. but I guess I need to change it anyways!

Comment: BTW, why did you put the `script` tag inside the `div`?

Comment: It is for styling purposes. and the script should be in the <head> element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the element id-search which hides in IE the function `search` of the global object:

```
<input id="search" onclick="search()" type="button" value="Search"/>
```

Should be:

```
<input id="search-suffix" onclick="search()" type="button" value="Search"/>
```

P.S.

[`int` is a reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyab5c8.aspx) in javascript though it doesn't do anything in the meanwhile, just like `class` and `private` etc', thus should be avoided.